# Sanitize front-end entry form field

Tags: filter, frontend-form

If I'm enabling a user to post to Craft using the front-end entry form, is there a way that I can sanitize the title of a post?

I'm looking to apply AP formatting to titles.

I know Stephen has a plugin [Entitle](https://github.com/experience/entitle.craft-plugin) that does this but I'd rather have it on the initial submission.

This is a JS app so I can't do it on the Twig side.

Comment: The JS app eventually POSTs the entry to Craft/PHP, correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely not rely on client-side validation. It's fine to do it from a UX point of view, but you should also be doing it server-side as well.

If this is a Vue app, write a custom validator for [Vee Validate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate)